# Exceção no Split()

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho em meu sistema uma indexação de termos, saber qual palavra está sendo mais usada entre as mensagens dos usuários, para isso, criei uma classe `Termos` e fiz um laço para que gere um novo objeto para cada palavra, assim, saberei em qual Fluxo(Página de um usuário) e Informação(Mensagem dentro do Fluxo) foi utilizada esse Termo.

Minha duvida é a seguinte: Caso o usuário digite algo do tipo "Olá! Tudo bem?" ele vai salvar "Olá!" e "bem?" junto com alguns elementos que não quero, vírgulas, exclamações e caracteres especiais. É possível definir exceções para isso? "Dizer" para o Split() não pegar esses caracteres?

Segue o trecho do código que estou utilizando:

**Termos.cs**

```
namespace ProjetoASPNETMVC.Models
{
    public class Termos
    {
        [Key]
        public int TermoID { get; set; }
        public String Palavra { get; set; }
        public Fluxo Fluxo { get; set; }
        public Informacao Informacao { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**InformacaoController.cs**

```
for (int x = 0; x < i.Mensagem.Split(' ').Length; x++)
                {
                    Termos termo = new Termos();
                    termo.Palavra = i.Mensagem.Split(' ')[x].ToUpper();
                    termo.Fluxo = db.Fluxo.ToList().Where(j => j.Informacoes.Contains(i)).FirstOrDefault();
                    termo.Informacao = i;
                    db.Termos.Add(termo);
                }
```

Imagino que seja possível fazer isso se contar caractere a caractere, gostaria de uma outra alternativa, imagino que se for checar letra por letra irá acabar com o desempenho do sistema.

Comment: Não entendi bem o que você deseja fazer, mas já posso adiantar que o `Split()` não vai resolver. O que você está fazendo deve fazer sentido para você, mas quem não sabe o que é, não dá para saber qual é o objetivo. Alguma coisa me diz que até a organização do projeto está errada, mas isso é outro assunto.

Comment: Preciso separar uma mensagem, e criar um objeto com cada palavra dessa mensagem para saber quantas vezes aquela palavra foi usada no sistema, mas se um usuário digita "Ola", e um outro digita "Ola!", vão ser palavras diferentes, queria saber como não contar caracteres especiais.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode tentar uma abordagem diferente. Antes de realizar o `split` você pode realizar a "Limpeza" da `string`, retirando os caracteres indesejados.

Seguindo o seu exemplo ficaria assim:

```
var padrao = @"[^\w\s]";
var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(padrao);

//Realiza a "Limpeza" da string
Mensagem = regex.Replace(Mensagem, string.Empty);

for (int x = 0; x < i.Mensagem.Split(' ').Length; x++)
{
    Termos termo = new Termos();
    termo.Palavra = i.Mensagem.Split(' ')[x].ToUpper();
    termo.Fluxo = db.Fluxo.ToList().Where(j => j.Informacoes.Contains(i)).FirstOrDefault();
    termo.Informacao = i;
    db.Termos.Add(termo);
}
```

Repare que a mudança foi realizada no conteúdo da variável `Mensagem` antes do `split` no laço `for`.

Detalhes da `Regex`:
[   #Início de bloco de carácter.
^   #Negação. Não esses caracteres (letras, números).
\w  #caracteres de palavras.
\s  #Caracteres de espaço.
]   #Fim de bloco de carácter.

A `Regex` utilizada nesta resposta foi baseada [nesta resposta do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871793/remove-punctuation-from-string-with-regex)

Comment: O VS ta apontando um erro em "\w\s", "Unrecognized escape sequence"

Comment: Modifiquei a resposta. Tem que colocar o `@` antes da string do padrão